# Expected value - No consecutive heads sequence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

> Problem: Suppose that you flip a coin $n$ times and it turns out that
> no consecutive heads appear in the sequence. Let $E(n)$ be the
> expected number of heads that appear given this information. Find $
>  \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{E(n)}{n}$. The answer is in the form of$\frac{a}{b+\sqrt{c}}$ for integers a,b,c with minimal c.

My approach:
Any sequence of n coins having exactly k heads (none consecutive) will be of the form T...THT...THT...THT...T
Let $x_1$ be the number of T's before the first H. Similarly define $x_i$ for i = $2,3,...,k+1$

Here, $\quad x_1$ and $x_{k+1}$ can be $0,1,... $ $\quad$ but $\quad$ $\forall$ i = $2,..,k\quad$ $ x_i = 1,2,...\quad$ (since we want no consecutive heads)

In order to use the multinomial approach, define new variables $y_i = x_i-1 $ for these $k-1$ variables.

Now, the number of ways to get such a sequence with k heads (no consecutive) = number of sol of the equation:

> $x_1 + y_2+y_3+...+y_k+x_{k+1} = n - k,$ where all variables $\in 0, 1,..$

After getting the general term for the above, taking the summation over k and dividing by total number of possible outcomes and taking the limit of n.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{E(n)}n = \frac1n \left( \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{k=(n+1)/2} k\cdot {{n-k+1} \choose {k}}}{\sum_{k=0}^{k=(n+1)/2} {{n-k+1} \choose {k}}} \right) $$

I can't seem to simplify the numerator. I've tried everything. Is this the correct approach? Is there a better one? Either way how do I find the above limit?

Comment: The denominator resembles sum of shallow diagonal of the Pascal's so I suspect it's a Fibonacci number. BTW, you meant limit on n instead of x.

Comment: Good sequences of length $n$ either start with $T$ or $HT$ and are then followed by shorter good sequences, so you can work recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_n$ be a random variable modeling the number of Heads in a sequence of $n$ tosses.

You're looking for
$E[S_n| \text{no }HH]$.
Conditioning on the outcome of the first toss,
$$
\begin{aligned}
E[S_n| \text{no }HH] 
&= 
P(X_1=H|\text{no }HH)E[S_n| \text{no }HH, X_1=H] + 
P(X_1=T|\text{no }HH)E[S_n| \text{no }HH, X_1=T]
\\&=
P(X_1=H|\text{no }HH)E[S_n| \text{no }HH, X_1=H]+
P(X_1=T|\text{no }HH)E[S_{n-1}| \text{no }HH].
\end{aligned}
$$
Given that $X_1=T$, the possible heads only appear at a rank $\geq 2$, hence you're essentially switching to an experiment with $n-1$ tosses instead of $n$, thus $E[S_n| \text{no }HH, X_1=T] = E[S_{n-1}| \text{no }HH]$.

Conditioning on the second toss and similar arguments yield
$$E[S_n| \text{no }HH, X_1=H] = 1+E[S_{n-2}| \text{no }HH].$$

Leting $e_n=E[S_n| \text{no }HH] $ and $r_n =P(X_1=H|\text{no }HH)$, we have obtained the relation
$$e_n = r_n(1+e_{n-2}) + (1-r_n) e_{n-1},$$
with initial values $e_1=\frac 12$ and $e_2=\frac 23$.

---

Define additionally $p_n = E[\text{no }HH|X_1=H]$ and $q_n=E[\text{no }HH|X_1=T]$. Conditioning on the second toss, we have
$$p_n = \frac 12 q_{n-1}$$
and
$$q_n = \frac 14 q_{n-2}  +\frac 12 q_{n-1},$$
with initial values $q_1=q_2=1$.
Therefore, $$q_n =\frac{2 \left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\right)^n}{\sqrt{5}+1}+\frac{6 \left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\right)^n}{\sqrt{5} \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)}+\frac{4 \left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)^n}{\sqrt{5} \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)}$$
and we get a closed form for $p_n$.
By Bayes formula, $$r_n=\frac{p_n}{p_n+q_n}=\frac{\left(\sqrt{5}+5\right) 4^n \left(\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)\right)^n-\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)\right)^n\right)}{\left(\sqrt{5}-5\right) (-1)^n \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)^n+2 \left(2 \sqrt{5}+5\right) \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)^n}.$$

---

Recall that the recurrence relation is
$$e_n = r_n(1+e_{n-2}) + (1-r_n) e_{n-1},$$
with initial values $e_1=\frac 12$ and $e_2=\frac 23$.
It seems unlikely that it can be solved in closed form.

However, $r_n$ converges quickly to $\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.
An "approximate" recurrence relation is then
$$\hat e_n = \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}(1+\hat e_{n-2}) + (1-\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}) \hat e_{n-1},$$
which has a closed form and we have
$$\lim_n \frac{\hat e_n}{n} = \frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{10} = \frac 2{5+\sqrt 5}.$$

Comment: Is your formula correct?  For $n=3$, the good sequences are $TTT, TTH, THT, HTT, HTH$.  Thus the probability that you get $(0,1,2)$ heads is $ \left(\frac 15,\frac 35,\frac 15\right)$ so the expected number is $0\times \frac 15+1\times \frac 35+2\times \frac 15=1$, no?  But of course you get $e_3=1+\frac 1{36}+\frac 1{18}=\frac {13}{12}$.

Comment: @lulu It seems I made a mistake in stating that $\{X_1=H\}$ and $\{\text{no }HH\}$ are independent. What do you think ?

Comment: I didn't look at your computation, just the result.  The recursive method I sketched in the comments is easy enough, though I doubt it leads to a pleasant closed form.  The answer will, I think,  be a fraction with numerator  from [A001629](https://oeis.org/A001629) and of course the denominators are the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @lulu I've corrected my recurrence relation. It is now $$e_n = r_n(1+e_{n-2}) + (1-r_n) e_{n-1}$$ where $r_n$ is given above. With $n=3$ I get the correct result $e_3=r_3(1+\frac 12) + (1-r_3)\frac 23 = 1$.

Comment: @DevanshAgarwal Is the result $\frac 2{5+\sqrt 5}$ given by the approximate recurrence relation correct ?

Comment: Note that $r_n$ is easily expressed as a ratio of Fibonacci numbers, since the number of good strings of length $n$ is a Fibonacci number.  Anyway, this formula looks good.  (+1)

Comment: @GabrielRomon Yes it is correct.